# Values stays the same after updating a struct array value

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a file which contains `2^32` key/value pairs like that;

```
32410806935257552 7355088504912337885
32422108164434515 8864339902215816897
32476145725020530 3183682744179377405
32554129507725755 7487866067392975840
32556703862039701 6580190515895793022
32576110112978588 468697310917255961
32589559935917707 757063057981860288
32724197203660231 4397507527199428746
32740607750878547 497049298362389181
32804063187658851 690408619066859126
....
```

I need to read that file and get the `1000 lines` every time I need.

I am using the function below for this;

```
void setChunk(pair* pairs, int setNumber, FILE *file){
    int start = setNumber * 1000;
    int finish = start + 1000; 
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char line [c];
    char *search = " ";

    printf("chunk is set between %d and %d\n", start, finish);
    if ( file != NULL ){

        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {
            if (count >= start && count < finish)
            {  
                pairs[i].key = strdup(strtok(line, search));

                pairs[i].value = strdup(strtok(NULL, search));

                i++;
            }

            count++;
        }   
    }
}
```

I am taking the `first 1000 thousands key/value` pair and write into the `struct array (pairs)` with no problem. Then I try to get next one thousands pairs but, the key/value struct array stays the same. I couldn't update its content. What can be the reason for this?

note: `setNumber` defines the which one thousands pairs I will take. If it is `0`, I get the lines between `0-1000`, if it is `18`, I get the lines `18000-19000`.

I'm calling setChunk funtion in a loop like this;

```
for(j=0; j<=fileNumber; j++){
        if ( file[j] != NULL )
        {
            printf("%d. chunks is started to fill\n", j);
            pairs[j] = malloc(1000 * sizeof(pair));
            setChunk(pairs[j],setnumber[j],file[j]);
            setnumber[j]+=1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you remember to rewind the file? `start` will be lines from the start of the file.

Comment: How do you call `setChunk`? Do you rewind the file between calls?

Comment: Actually I have a file array and I keep the pointers of all the files.  So I am updating the question to tell how I call the setChunk funtions

Comment: It would be a very good idea to insert code to validate the `setNumber` value is in the range (inclusive) 0...31

Comment: regarding this line: `char line [c];`   is 'c' some #define value?  if not, then this code will not work correctly.  perhaps you meant something similar to: `char line [100];`?

Comment: the posted code contains some `magic` numbers.   `magic` numbers make code more difficult to understand and a real headache to maintain.  Suggest inserting #defines or an enum with meaningful names.  Then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: @user3629249 yes it is exactly like that. it is defined as 41 char because my every line can be maximum 41

Comment: the returned values from `strtok()` and `strdup()`  should always be checked to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: "Keeping the pointers to all the files?" All what files, you mention one file.

Comment: I suspect `setnumber[j]` whatever it's for. Correct (`0`) for the first call, not on subsequent.

Comment: when #define'ing or enum definitions for values, it is standard programming practice to make the names all capitals, using underscore char to separate root words in the name AND for the name to be meaningful.  'c', in this context is not meaningful.   Suggest something similar to : `#define MAX_LINE_LEN (41)`  and using that name instead of 'c'

Comment: how is the calling sequence `pairs[]` defined?  it looks like it might be a struct pair ** pairs[x] = {NULL}`   Is that correct?

Comment: @Weather Vane  I was very new to the file operations so I didn't I understood when you said about rewinding the file. I just adde `rewind(file);` before the while loop and it is worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

regarding these lines:

```
setChunk(pairs[j],setnumber[j],file[j]); 
setnumber[j]+=1;`
```

the `setnumber` is an array,

(lets assume it is initialized to all 0s.)

So entry setnumber[0] is passed on the first call. then setnumber[0] is incremented to 1

On the next call setnumber[1] is passed on the call, then setnumber [1] is incremented to 1.

I.E. on every call the second parameter is always 0.

Comment: I will check this but I don't think so this is the problem. Because I printed out this value. It is increasing correctly. I guess the problem is about strdup part. I mean I read the line which I need, but when assigning to the pairs array, the old values stays. I just can't write the new values to that array.

Comment: you do realize the pairs array needs to be some 10000 entries and each iteration calling the sub function will fill a different part of the pairs array.