# fgets() doesn't continue until to the end of the file in the while loop

Tags: c, file-io, eof

I need to read a file until its end, but it interrupts before the end. Here is my file;

```
8378749330196451143 7761927347639996843
3597172149842452783 2722311582032048570
6413963814675220040 151985128848019557
2797849130305409931 7006855242872793130
2312483514986641752 4723009976223322840
6299327914512777856 8560986736619134288
7840374864908954188 6413325942318176938
7120263339634576853 5721019237600873947
4064508404151769878 8332513917413808407
1131946326472490896 8768732125304950625
2593825059274639432 4898919688177170005
1152428805919273221 4955899780218674181
4762291655892416501 1286985264509566046
1098025338340897985 4952984927278789363
2524421559647997815 8843945302342585201
```

I am using this part of code for getting the lines;

```
file = fopen ( buffer, "r" );
    if ( file != NULL ){
            while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) {
                // Token will point to the part before the =.
                pairs[i].key = strdup(strtok(line, search));
                // Token will point to the part after the =.
                pairs[i].value = strdup(strtok(NULL, search));

                i++;
              }
    }
```

It works, but not till the end. After reading the part below while loop ends. What can be the reason for this? Every line end with a \n symbol.

```
8378749330196451143 7761927347639996843
3597172149842452783 2722311582032048570
6413963814675220040 151985128848019557
2797849130305409931 7006855242872793130
2312483514986641752 4723009976223322840
6299327914512777856 8560986736619134288
7840374864908954188 6413325942318176938
7120263339634576853 572101923
```

Note: I got a screenshot from an editor that shows marks

[image]

Comment: Dunno.  You should probably debug it.

Comment: When I made a minimal example from the information you posted, making reasonable assumptions about the code not shown, it works. So your problem lies elsewhere, or in `line` too short, or `strdup` or `strtok` returning `NULL`, or `search` not including every delimitor possible. As ever, you **must** post a MCVE that allows commenters to replicate the problem.

Comment: Note OP continues from previously asked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201531/values-stays-the-same-after-updating-a-struct-array-value

Comment: From your recent edit, it seems you have read in more than 500,000 data lines, allocating memory for them all (with `strdup`). And yet you have not checked the return values from `strdup` or from `strtok`, a basic error.

Comment: Did you remember to `free` the memory acquired by `strdup` after each batch of reads (referring to previous question on your topic)?

Comment: I have tried to check the tokens and any of the values return NULL. You are right I don't free the memory after a cycle for pairs.  Why it is required for strdub?

Comment: Post definition of `line`.

Comment: @chux comments in the previous question reveal that `char line [c]` "is defined as 41 char because my every line can be maximum 41". Now, there are 20 decimal digits max in a 64-bit `unsigned int`. Two of those plus a `space` make 41. *What about the string terminator?* But nowhere is the formal definition posted.

Comment: @Weather Vane Certainly OP _should_ be using a buffer of at least 43 or 44 (20+`' '`+20+`'\r'` + `'\n'` + `'\0'`).  Further there is no need for stinginess here.  I would use a 2x and some extra buffer, say 100 for things like leading/trailing spaces, `'\r'` and future growth to a 2x larger integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201531/values-stays-the-same-after-updating-a-struct-array-value) on this topic indicates you are processing data from file 1000 lines at a time, for each of these 1000 lines you call `strdup` twice (once for each data field in the text line). You also said "*I have a file which contains 2^32 key/value pairs*".

For each of these you call `strdup` twice, once for each data field. Now, `strdup` allocates memory to hold the string you want to be duplicated. With your massive quantity of data, that's an enormous amount of memory, and the program grinds to a halt through lack of it.

So I suggest that after processing each 1000 lines of input, you release the memory, something like this - please adapt to your needs, since you never show whole code.

```
for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    free(pairs[i].key);
    free(pairs[i].value);
}
```

It is essentially good practice to the check the return value of any library function that returns an error-hinting value. In the case of `strdup` that will tell you if you ran out of memory. In the case of `strtok` you'll know that a rogue line was in the file that you cannot interpret - perhaps an empty line at the end of the file terminated by `newline`.

Secondly, comments in that previous question reveal that `char line [c]`

> is defined as 41 char because my every line can be maximum 41.

Now, there are 20 decimal digits max in a 64-bit `unsigned int`. Two of those plus a `space` make 41. *What about the string terminator?* And what about the `newline` that will usually be on the end of the input obtained by `fgets`? I propose you change your definition of `c` (you never show it) to something like

```
#define c 50
```

as there is no reason to be tight with a single string length. When you call `strdup`, that will only allocate enough memory for the string length + terminator, so it's not a big waste of memory at all.

Comment: `c` should be at _least_ 43.  +1 for `'\0'`.  See [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243170/fgets-doesnt-continue-until-to-the-end-of-the-file-in-the-while-loop?noredirect=1#comment54294494_33243170)

Comment: @chux thanks, I thought that when the previous question was asked but forgot. Now revised whole answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is program which correctly reads the data from the file -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data{
    char *key;
    char *value;
}pairs[20];

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp; 
    int i=0;
    char line[255],search[2]=" ";
    char *token;
    fp=fopen("Results.txt","r");
    if(fp!=NULL){
       while(fgets(line,sizeof line,fp)!=NULL){            // read from file 
         pairs[i].key=NULL;                // setting to NULL 
         pairs[i].value=NULL;              // setting to NULL 
         token=strtok(line, search);
         if(token!=NULL){             // check its return 
              pairs[i].key = strdup(token);
           }
         token=strtok(NULL, search);
         if(token!=NULL){            // check its return             
             pairs[i].value = strdup(token);
         }            
         if(pairs[i].key!=NULL && pairs[i].value!=NULL)      //check return from strdup
              printf("%s %s\n",pairs[i].key,pairs[i].value);  //print values
           i++;
        }
    }
   for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
      free( pairs[i].key);
      free( pairs[i].value);
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

I didn't know your declarations , so did accordingly .

Comment: @WeatherVane Added that :-)

Comment: I think you should take abortive action on `NULL` rather than skip. The `pairs` array might not already contain `NULL` since from the previous OP question (see above comment) he is probably recycling the array.

Comment: @WeatherVane  But I am checking for `return` of `strdup` which would return `NULL` on failure regardless of any previous data .So, that shouldn't be any problem . Correct me if I am wrong :-)

Comment: My point was you don't set the `pairs` field after a failed `strtok` yet you go on to check it for `NULL`. From the previous OP question, `pairs` might already contain pointers from previous iteration.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay , so if `strtok` fails I should set `pairs` to `NULL` for next checking .

Comment: Set to `NULL` *first*

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah , I shall do that . I was completely off-topic in that . Thanks for pointing it out .